# How to improve performance of Bulk Inserts in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, toad

```
env: windows 10 
version mysql 5.7
Ram 32GB
ide : toad mysql
```

i have sufficient hardware requirement but issue is the performance of insert into simple table that does not have any relation ships. i need to have index on the table.

table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `2017` (
  `MOB_NO` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CAF_SLNO` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CNAME` varchar(58) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ACT_DATE` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `2017_index` (`MOB_NO`,`ACT_DATE`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I am using above for inserting the records into table. with out index it took around 30 min where as with indexing it took 22 hrs still going on.

```
SET autocommit=0;
SET unique_checks=0;
SET foreign_key_checks=0;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:/base/test/2017/2017.txt' 
INTO TABLE 2017COLUMNS TERMINATED BY '|';
commit;
```

i have seen suggestion to change cnf file, Could not find any in my machine.

Comment: 30 minutes for how many records?

Comment: all the records into databases exactly is 39.22 sec

Comment: I thought you said it takes 30 minutes without the index

Comment: it takes 39min and 22 sec  with out index and with indexing it take 22 hrs still on.

Comment: You still haven't answered the question: how many records are you trying to insert?

Comment: Count 11,308,147.
 i have 5 table with this count and more than this

Comment: You should ask for this to be migrated to [dba.se]

Comment: it should be quite obvious, but please don't use Indian words here

Comment: my apologies for indian indian words

Comment: You can try to split file into 2-4 chunks and load them in parallel. And definitely turn off inexes when loading.

Comment: I am able to achieve it finally to 2 hrs by adding the following in ini file
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode =2
sync_binlog=1
bulk_insert_buffer_size=512M
key_buffer_size=512M

read_buffer = 50M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding following lines in my.ini. I am able to achieve it.

```
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode =2
sync_binlog=1
bulk_insert_buffer_size=512M
key_buffer_size=512M
read_buffer = 50M
```

and **innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2**, i have seen in another link where it said that it increase speed to 160x.
Output performance :more than 24hr to 2 hrs

Answer (score 0):

If you begin with an empty table, create it without any indexes.  Then, after fully populating the table, adding an index is reported to be faster than inserting with the index already in place.

See:

- [MySQL optimizing INSERT speed being slowed down because of indices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16988019/198536)
- [Is it better to create an index before filling a table with data, or after the data is in place?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3688755/198536)

Possibly helpful:  [Create an index on a huge MySQL production table without table locking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14248906/198536)

Comment: I have tried few suggestion mentioned in other questions 1. Alter table after adding data 2 create table dump and then create index 3. Create table with index and dump data. 4 change in initiative file which worked for me as the insertion rate increased