# Changing innodb_io_capacity_max parameter in MYSQL8 for low IOPS Azure instance

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-innodb-cluster

I am using Mysql 8 on ubuntu 18 , the default  value of innodb_io_capacity_max is 2000 . If I reduce it to 500 . will it be any issue if I load some big size file 5GB . Consider my setup 2 CPU vcore, 8GB RAM Azure instance  ( Ubuntu 18) . . My consideration is that it should not failed rather due to innodb_io_capacity_max value change   than  slow loading has been accepted

Comment: why you want to reduce it to 500?

Comment: @Debashis, If my answer is usful to you, please don't foget to vote it up~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's take a look at what is `innodb_io_capacity_max` in [office doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-configuring-io-capacity.html):

> If **flushing activity falls behind**, InnoDB can flush more aggressively,
> at a higher rate of I/O operations per second (IOPS) than defined by
> the `innodb_io_capacity` variable. The `innodb_io_capacity_max` variable
> defines a maximum number of IOPS performed by InnoDB background tasks
> in such situations.
>
> If you specify an `innodb_io_capacity` setting at startup but do not
> specify a value for `innodb_io_capacity_max`, innodb_io_capacity_max
> defaults to twice the value of `innodb_io_capacity`, with a minimum
> value of 2000.

Therefore, `innodb_io_capacity_max` is a **maximum number of IOPS** performed by InnoDB background tasks **when flushing activity falls behind**

When you reduced it to 500, it means **maximum number of IOPS when flushing activity falls behind** is changed to 500.

It **may** slow your loading operations. However, the performance of loading big file is not only related to **number of IOPS** of flushing to disk. There would be other key points:

1. Hardware Performance: How about the iops of your Azure instance's disk.
2. Change buffer size: Benifit for secondary index
3. Redo log file size and file count: if redo log file size or file count is too small, mysql have to stop loading new insert data till enough dirty pages are flushed to disk.
4. innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct value: if this value is too low, the flushing rate will automatically increase,
5. concurent thread number of loading: Too have load will cause `page_cleaner` warning.
   ....

For Question, `will it be any issue if I load some big size file 5GB`, I think there would be some warnings of loading performance and should have no failures.

When trying to answer your question, I found 2 other questions which may be helpful for you. The links are below. This gentleman, `@Bill Karwin` give very helpful explainations in the answers of both questions.

- [How to solve mysql warning: “InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended
  loop took XXX ms. The settings might not be optimal ”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41134785/how-to-solve-mysql-warning-innodb-page-cleaner-1000ms-intended-loop-took-xxx/41155396#41155396)
- [InnoDB indexes before and after importing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50974173/innodb-indexes-before-and-after-importing)