# Is mysql index creating all done on table with millions of rows, after 'create index' executed?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm curious about what happend after execute "create index xxx" on a table of millions of rows.

According to this question [Is it better to create an index before filling a table with data, or after the data is in place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688731/is-it-better-to-create-an-index-before-filling-a-table-with-data-or-after-the-d),

1 million rows cost 4 seconds to create indexes, it seems fast enough.

I'm not sure if all data read and all the b+ tree index built during the 4 seconds, or the indexes are not built for whole table immediately?

Comment: No, the index should in fact build using the entire table's data, and also, whenever you do subsequent DML operations, MySQL should also rebuild/refresh the index.  Indexing several millions rows doesn't necessarily have to take that long, depending on the data and the index.

Comment: Thanks Tim, so all indexes are created synchronously after create index, and take effect for table query immediately？

Comment: [Read here for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244685/create-an-index-on-a-huge-mysql-production-table-without-table-locking).  MySQL will not block reads/writes while the index is being created, but you still won't be able to use it until it has finished getting created.

Comment: clear enough, thanks.